# Limiting the number of words PHP Magento Instant Search

Tags: php, string, magento, limit

I'm trying to limit the amount of words that get displayed as they are running off the page. I have a small script I use in certain places but I can't seem to get anything to work in this context. Here's the peace of code:

```
    }
    $html .=" <button type='button' class='button-search-buy' onclick='javascript:document.productAddToCartForm.submit()'><span>". $product_helper->__(' ') ."</span></button>";
    $html .="</fieldset>";
}


$html .="<div id='description'><h4 style='margin:5px 0 3px 0'><span style='color:#e26703'>".Mage::helper("catalog/product")->__("Quick Overview")."</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style='font-size:10px' href='".$product_url."'  target='_self'>".$product_helper->__('View Detail')."</a></h4>"
            . $product->getShortDescription() <-------Right here            
      ."</div>"     
."</div>
  </div></form>";
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-json');
 $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);
```

Here's some code I found that works but I can't figure ouit how to make it work with this open type php code as above.

```
<?php $sdesc2 = $_product->getShortDescription();
$sdesc2 = trim($sdesc2);
$limit = 120;
    if (strlen($sdesc2) > $limit) {
      $sdesc2 = substr($sdesc2, 0, strrpos(substr($sdesc2, 0, $limit), ' '));
    } ?>
<?php echo $sdesc2."..."; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $sdesc2 = $product->getShortDescription();
$sdesc2 = trim($sdesc2);
$limit = 120;
    if (strlen($sdesc2) > $limit) {
      $sdesc2 = substr($sdesc2, 0, strrpos(substr($sdesc2, 0, $limit), ' '));
    } ?>

$html .="<div id='description'><h4 style='margin:5px 0 3px 0'><span style='color:#e26703'>".Mage::helper("catalog/product")->__("Quick Overview")."</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style='font-size:10px' href='".$product_url."'  target='_self'>".$product_helper->__('View Detail')."</a></h4>"
        . $sdesc2 ."</div>"
```

Comment: I tried your code but it made it stop working. It just keeps searching but doesn't return and items. Maybe you need to see more of the code.

Comment: my code is your code which you said you want to integrate. all it does is move the placement to a variable and attach to the string construction. So the part that is not working probably is the code you originally posted.

Comment: I understand but I'm using this code in template files and it works. There is something different about this search script. I've tried for hours to get it to work on this Instant search with no luck. anyway it's not mission critical or nothing.